# Loading images in Java Web Start applet

Tags: java, image, applet, java-web-start

In normal applets, I use this to load images into JLabels

```
    Image back2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "images/blank_blue.png");
    ImageIcon background2Icon = new ImageIcon(back2);
    JLabel pic2 = new JLabel(background2Icon);
```

When I tried doing this with a Java Web Start applet, nothing appeared.
In the Java Console, it said this 
`basic: Loaded image: file:/C:/Users/jdfksl/Desktop/webStartTest/images/blank_blue.png`
And there was no error, but it wouldn't appear.

I got images to load in JLabels that work in Java Web Start this way

```
BufferedImage image=null;
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("images/ghast_skin.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But, I wanted a shorter way of loading images.
Is there any other option?

This is my jnlp file content

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jnlp href="jws_tester.jnlp">
     <information>
       <title>JWS tester</title>
       <vendor>HTZ.</vendor>
       <description>Testing with JWS</description>
       <offline-allowed />
     </information>
     <resources>
       <j2se version="1.4+"
             href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
       <jar href="tester.jar" main="true" />
       <!-- Specify if using JNLP extensions
                                <extension name="SomeExtension"
                  href="http://some.server.com/some_extension.jnlp" />
                                -->
     </resources>

     <security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>

     <applet-desc 
         name="JWS tester"
         main-class="mather.Main"
         width="900"
         height="600">
     </applet-desc>
 </jnlp>
```

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP?  Has it been validated using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I ran JaNeLA and it says in yellow `Content type content/unknown does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file` and in red `The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed`. I have no idea what that means

Comment: @AndrewThompson Actually, from the JaNeLA help, it says that `It is typical for JNLP files checked from the local file system to be of incorrect type.`, so the 'content type unknown' should be fine

Comment: *"I have no idea what that means"*  There are more details in the JaNeLA app. (e.g. click on the error). But then, I could tell you what it means if you answered my first question..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I posted my JNLP file, is that what you wanted?

Comment: That JNLP is definitely invalid 1) JaNeLA should be showing errors (in red). 2) Which line shows the error `The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed`? 3) But most relevant to the problem, [add a `document-base` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#applet_desc).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add the images to your build path and access the image from any class like this.

```
new ImageIcon(TestClass.class.getResource("/image.png"));
```

In this approach the image will be added to your jar file so your jar file may get bulkier.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Image image = new ImageIcon("path").getImage();
```

Edit: this `path` can be either the full path of you image, or a relative path to your project folder. IE, if your **image path** is:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\YourProject\src\resource\image.png
```

You may access it by

```
src\resource\image.png
```

Comment: An applet cannot access a resource on the server as a `File`, nor can that access an embedded resource.  This is an entirely inappropriate strategy for loading the image in this use-case.